# Portfolio Performance Attribution Using Carino Smoothing

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio, asset-allocation, performance

I'm trying to conduct portfolio performance attribution using Carino smoothing, but it seems that the active returns do not match and I don't know why. Here is the example I use:

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
portfolio &R_{t1} &R_{t2}&R_{t3}&R_{t4}&w_{t1}&w_{t2}&w_{t3}&w_{t4}\\
\hline
sector1 &-0.06& 0.04&   0.04&   0.04    &0.30&  0.40&   0.20    &0.20\\
\hline
sector2 &0.02 & -0.12   &-0.02  &0.06 & 0.10 &  0.40    &0.10 & 0.20  \\
\hline
sector3 &-0.12  &0.04 & 0.21 &  0.06 &  0.60    &0.20 & 0.70 &  0.60 \\
\hline
\end{array}

\begin{array} {|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|}
\hline
benchmark &R_{t1} &R_{t2}&R_{t3}&R_{t4}&w_{t1}&w_{t2}&w_{t3}&w_{t4}\\
\hline
sector1 &0.00 & 0.03 &  -0.06   &0.08   &0.10 & 0.10    &0.30   &0.40 \\
\hline
sector2 &0.04 & 0.00 &  -0.04&  0.06 &  0.20 &  0.40 &  0.20 &  0.20 \\
\hline
sector3 &0.14   &0.00 & -0.10&  0.00 &  0.70    &0.50   &0.50 & 0.40 \\
\hline
\end{array}

So I calculate the portfolio return 15.06% and benchmark return 10.84%, and thus the active return is 4.21%. Then, by using Carino smoothing, I get those coefficients: $k = 0.8854, k_1 = 0.9996, k_2 = 1.0054, k_3 = 1.0004, k_4 = 0.8696 $. I also calculate the asset allocation, security selection and interaction term for single period and use those coefficients to adjust them. For example:
$$Asset Allocation_{t, adjusted} = Asset Allocation_t * k_t / k$$

After the adjustment, I sum up all those effects for 4 periods and find that the portfolio return minus the benchmark return becomes nearly 2% (I'm quite confused about this). I would expect the active return should be the same as the previous one, but it's far less than 4.21%. I guess there are some problems with how to use adjusted returns. Could someone explain how to use Carino attribution when I want to calculate the asset allocation, security selection, interaction for multiperiod for this example?

Comment: Excuse me but, when I compute the benchmark returns I get [0.106 0.003 -0.076 0.044] which add up to 0.077 and compound to 0.07011. It does not match your 10.84 pct. Did I make a stupid error or is there a typo somewhere or something else.

Comment: Ah, I guess that's where the problem lies! When I imported benchmark data into excel, I made a mistake that the columns did not match. Thank you so much! I thought there were some problems with my adjustment previously. hahaha that's sad.